# Look up data via URL parameter

Tags: ruby, express, sinatra

I'm pretty knowledgeable about Express and am wondering if Sinatra has a feature similar to what I use in my Express apps.

Take this Express example:

```js
app.param('userId', function(req, res, next, id) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    if (!err) req.viewedUser = user;
    return next();
  });
});
```

If any route includes the `:userId` in the url, we automatically grab the user based on the param value, then set it so it's usable in the routes that include the parameter:

```js
app.get('/users/:userId', function(req, res, next, id) {
  // req.viewedUser is now the user defined in app.param()
  res.render("edit-user" {
    user: req.viewedUser
  });
});
```

Basically, if a URL path parameter is hit, make it so the data is automatically looked up and make it so it's usable in other routes.

Is there some sort of way of doing this with Sinatra?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code conversion site, so it behooves you to supply the Ruby code you're attempting to use to solve the problem and we'll help you fix it. It is possible to do what you're asking, but without an idea of what your Sinatra code looks like we'll write code that is totally unrelated to yours which might not serve you well.

Comment: @theTinMan I'm not asking for a code conversion, I'm asking if there is a way to do this using the built in functions of Sinatra.  The above code is how I would do it in Express (which has some level of feature parity with Sinatra), so I added it to show as an example of the results I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking but I think that you are asking how to access data from the query string, e.g. if you go to `https://www.example.com/index?q=aoiehgoaiwghe&p=21490719` the way to see what `q` and `p` are equal to would be to use `params[:q]` to get what `q` is and `params[:p]` to get what `p` is.

**edit** So I think you are asking how to 1) check if there is userId in the query string then 2) if there is retrieve it. If that is what you are asking then here is the solution:

```
If params[:userId] != nil
    record == Table.find_by(user_id:params[:userId])
end
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear.  One of the tokens in my URL correlates to a record's ID.  If the URL contains the token I would like to look up these records and check for invalid ID's in one central place, allowing the individual routes to use that information that was looked up in the previous call. Express provides an `app.param` method that gets called if any URL's contain an `:id` (or whatever token you specify) in the URL.

Comment: Setting a global variable based on lookup would work, but I'm more looking for something that's more baked-in to the framework.  Currently I've got a `get '/users/:userId/?*'` route that does basically the above (but then passes the connection to the next route handler), but a solution to that seems far from ideal (for example, what if I wanted a `get '/orders/:userId` route?)